# Corrupt information from socket in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

This problem started recently being that it didn't happen before (it happened after started to implement pickle through the code)

Here is the client's code for it:

```
largo = self.usuario.recv(4)
largo = int.from_bytes(largo, 'little')
print(largo)
canciones = self.usuario.recv(largo)
canciones = pickle.loads(canciones)
print('canciones: {}'.format(canciones))
```

Here is the server's code:

```
canciones = pickle.dumps(dire) #dire es la lista que quiero enviar
largo = len(canciones).to_bytes(4,'little')
client_socket.send(largo)
client_socket.send(canciones)
```

I make sure there is any extra bytes before this part, so both receive and send exactly what it should. When I print the len of the data right before and after sending it, I get 230 in the server, and 13 in the client, and when I print the bytes of each number, before passing them to int, I get b'\xe6\x00\x00\x00' in the server and b'\r\x00\x00\x00' in the client.

This is for an assignment.

**Edit:**

When I put socket.recv(230) on the next item, the information recieved is 345 bytes long, which makes no sense

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: recv does not guarantee to return the full amount of data requested; in general, you must loop until you get the data you requested, and check for error conditions after every call. You may find the `MSG_WAITALL` flag simplifies some things.